# Check the protocol of an external URL in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, redirect

Is there a way to check what the protocol is of an external site using NodeJS.

For example, for the purposes of URL shortening, people can provide a url, if they omit http or https, I'd check which it should be and add it.

I know I can just redirect users without the protocol, but I'm just curious if there is a way to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can. First install `request-promise` and its dependency, `request`:

```
npm install request request-promise
```

Now we can write an async function to take a URL that might be missing its protocol and, if necessary, add it:

```
const rq = require('request-promise');

async function completeProtocol(url) {
  if (url.match(/^https?:/)) {
    // fine the way it is
    return url;
  }
  // https is preferred
  try {
    await rq(`https://${url}`, { method: 'HEAD' });
    // We got it, that's all we need to know
    return `https://${url}`;
  } catch (e) {
    return `http://${url}`;
  }
}
```

Bear in mind that making requests like this could take up resources on your server particularly if someone spams a lot of these. You can mitigate that by passing `timeout: 2000` as an option when calling `rq`.

Also consider only requesting the home page of the site, parsing off the rest of the URL, to mitigate the risk that this will be abused in some way. The protocol should be the same for the entire site.